# How do I write to an NSObject from within a C function that doesn't see Obj-C variables?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, multi-touch

I'm trying to get some code going that lets me display raw trackpad data from my macbook pro, like the app FingerMgmt. Unfortunately, no one seems to have the source for FingerMgmt. I did find some other source code that kind of works, however. I was able to NSLog the data I wanted to see like this:

```
int callback(int device, Finger *data, int nFingers, double timestamp, int frame) {


for (int i=0; i<nFingers; i++) {
    Finger *f = &data[i];
    NSLog(@"Frame %7d: Angle %6.2f, ellipse %6.3f x%6.3f; "
          "position (%6.3f,%6.3f) vel (%6.3f,%6.3f) "
          "ID %d, state %d [%d %d?] size %6.3f, %6.3f?\n",
          f->frame,
          f->angle * 90 / atan2(1,0),
          f->majorAxis,
          f->minorAxis,
          f->normalized.pos.x,
          f->normalized.pos.y,
          f->normalized.vel.x,
          f->normalized.vel.y,
          f->identifier, f->state, f->foo3, f->foo4,
          f->size, f->unk2);
    //todo-get data from raw C to obj-C variable
}


    return 0;
```

}

But whenever I try to store any of the data to an Obj-c string or variable, the C code does not see the variable as having been declared. Because of this, I cannot write to any text fields or graphical displays in Obj-C, and I cannot store the data to a variable that Obj-c can access.

Basically, I need a way to write to an Obj-C variable or object from within the callback.

On a side note, I had a very similar problem with an iPhone app a while back, and I ended up fixing it by somehow declaring the app delegate within the C code and writing to or reading from the variable like this-

```
me.delegate=(id <UIApplicationDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];//allows access to the delegate within C function
me.delegate.number0=5;//writes to this variable in the delegate
```

For some reason, I can not seem to adapt this to my current situation. I always get the error that "me" is undeclared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Objective-C method can access instance variables because it is automagically passed a hidden parameter with the public name `self` - any reference to an instance variable, say `fred`, is translated by the compiler into a field reference, say `self->fred` (and a similar translation for property references).

For your C function `callback` to access the fields of any object (or call an object's methods) you need to pass the function a reference to the object. Two simple ways:

1. Add an argument to the function. Many C callback protocols include a general "user defined" values which is passed around as `void *`, if you are calling one of these pass your object reference as this value and cast it within the C function back to the correct Objective-C type.
2. Pass the object via a global (or file static) variable, e.g. `static NSSomeType *objectForCallback;`. This method works when you're stuck with an existing C callback protocol which doesn't support a user defined value. However it is not thread or re-entrant safe as you are sharing a single static variable.

In both cases make sure the objected is `retain`'ed if you're not using garbage collection.

### In response to comment

Case 1: You will see C functions declared which (a) take a callback function and (b) a user-defined value to pass to that function on every call. For example:

```
typedef T ...;

T findMatching(T *buffer,                           // an array of T to search
               size_t count,                        // number of items in array
               int (*matcher)(T item, void *user),  // user function for match, 1st arg is item, 2nd user-supplied value
               void *userValue);                    // user-supplied value to pass to matcher
```

If you are faced with C function like this you can pass a (`retain`'ed if needed) Objective-C object as `userValue` and cast it back to its Objective-C type inside `matcher`. For example:

```
int myMatcher(T item, void *user)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary *)user;
    ...
}

- (void) someMethod
{
    NSMutableDictionary *sharedWithC = ...;
    ...
    T found = findMatching(buffer, count, myMatcher, (void *)sharedWithC);
    ...
}
```

Case 2: Objective-C *is* (a superset of) C. You declare a global just as you would in C. For example (little checking, not thread safe):

```
static NSMutableDictionary *myGlobalDictionary = nil; // "static" makes the variable only visible to code in the same file

- (void) setupTheSharedDictionary
{
    myGlobalDictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] retain];
}

- (void) releaseTheSharedDictionary
{
    if(myGlobalDictionary != nil)
    {
        [myGlobalDictionary release];
        myGlobalDictionary = nil;
    }
}
```

### In response to second comment

I'm guessing you are trying to use some third party (Google?) code. That code defines a callback protocol - a C function type. You cannot just redefine that C function type adding an extra argument and expect the third party code to magically cope!

So unless you intend to change the C you can use the second approach - store the reference to Objective-C object in a global. In your case this will be something like:

```
static MT2AppDelegate *sharedWithCAppDelegateReference;

int callback(...)
{
    ...
    [sharedWithCAppDelegateReference->L1 setStringValue:@"Hellofff"];
    ...
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    sharedWithCAppDelegateReference = self; // store so C can pick it up
    ...
    MTRegisterContactFrameCallback(dev, callback);
    ...
}
```

But remember this is not thread or re-entrant safe - you are effectively passing a function parameter via a global variable. If you need it to be thread/re-entrant safe you need to get a bit more involved.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this. I don't think my callback supports any user defined variables, and even if it did, I don't know how to pass my app delegate to it. I've tried everything I can think of... As for the second one, I don't really get this either-I can't seem to declare a static NSVariable. Also, how do you declare a global variable in objective-c? I've never had to do that, I always keep variables I need to be "global" in the app delegate and just define some getter/setter methods.

Comment: @wayager, don't pass the whole app delegate, just pass the data you need in a struct.

Comment: OK, still not getting it. Sorry, this is going over me right now. I just need to see it in action one time. At this point I'm just slapping void* pretty much anywhere it might work, and I'm really flying blind.  If it helps, here's my app delegate .m: http://pastebin.com/5zT2mb4J There's probably some random useless code in there at this point. Here's my .h: http://pastebin.com/VMNeLDh9   Sorry for being so clueless-this is what happens when you learn everything from random internet tutorials! :)

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks. If making it thread safe is important, can you link me to some info or give me a pointer on doing so?

Comment: Did a little research-Since only one thing (the callback) is messing with the text field, it doesn't need to be thread safe, does it?